# Bringing panel to front on a click of a button in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like some help with code so my panels get brought to front when I click a button.

I have tried

```
private void button22_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel4.BringToFront();
}
```

but that didn't seem to work for me.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how I could get this working?
I am in c# winforms.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Provide a complete code example.

Comment: I did add code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work fine. You code says `panel4` so I assume you have multiple panels.

If you have placed `panel3` on `panel4`, then `BringToFront()` will bring both forward and may look like there is no change. Make sure both panels have the form as their parent. You can do this by cut and paste, or making sure that you click the form canvas (not an existing panel) when you add the other panels.

The same for buttons, textboxes etc, if you draw them on to a panel, they will stay as is on that panel when you bring them forwards.